# Symbolicate Crash lock with QuincyKit not symbolicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, symbolicatecrash

i'm trying to symbolicate a crash using the amazing QuincyKit, but when i do it give me this log and i can't understand what is the problem, this is the log:

```
got symbolicator for /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.1 (11D201)/Symbols/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib, base address 375e5000
got symbolicator for /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.1 (11D201)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib, base address 381d3000
got symbolicator for /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.1 (11D201)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit, base address 2fcbf000
got symbolicator for /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.1 (11D201)/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib, base address 37c2e000
got symbolicator for /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.1 (11D201)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib, base address 3812e000
got symbolicator for /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.1 (11D201)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib, base address 3811a000
got symbolicator for /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TV_Files-fgjpomidyzioftdljnwyxaamguey/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TV Files.app/TV Files, base address 4000
got symbolicator for /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.1 (11D201)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib, base address 3824b000
got symbolicator for /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.1 (11D201)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation, base address 2ddb6000
got symbolicator for /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.1 (11D201)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib, base address 3814d000
got symbolicator for /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.1 (11D201)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices, base address 32332000
got symbolicator for /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.1 (11D201)/Symbols/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, base address 37ed3000
got symbolicator for /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.1 (11D201)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation, base address 2d3c6000
```

**EDIT:**

this is the crash log before the symbolicate:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x3953f1f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x394efff9 abort + 77
2   MyApp                             0x0045cee7 uncaught_exception_handler + 27
3   CoreFoundation                       0x2e4ae20d __handleUncaughtException + 581
4   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x38f8af6b _objc_terminate() + 175
5   libc++abi.dylib                      0x389551b3 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 79
6   libc++abi.dylib                      0x38954d17 __cxa_rethrow + 103
7   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x38f8ae2f objc_exception_rethrow + 43
8   CoreFoundation                       0x2e3e17df CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 643
9   CoreFoundation                       0x2e3e154b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
10  GraphicsServices                     0x3331b6d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
11  UIKit                                0x30d40891 UIApplicationMain + 1136
12  MyApp                             0x004474af main (main.m:17)
13  libdyld.dylib                        0x39488ab7 start + 2
```

and this is the crash log of the Thread crashed after the symbolication:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x3953f1f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x394efff9 abort + 77
2   MyApp                             0x0045cee7 uncaught_exception_handler + 27
3   CoreFoundation                       0x2e4ae20d __handleUncaughtException + 581
4   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x38f8af6b _objc_terminate() + 175
5   libc++abi.dylib                      0x389551b3 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 79
6   libc++abi.dylib                      0x38954d17 __cxa_rethrow + 103
7   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x38f8ae2f objc_exception_rethrow + 43
8   CoreFoundation                       0x2e3e17df CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 643
9   CoreFoundation                       0x2e3e154b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
10  GraphicsServices                     0x3331b6d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
11  UIKit                                0x30d40891 UIApplicationMain + 1136
12  MyApp                             0x004474af main (main.m:17)
13  libdyld.dylib                        0x39488ab7 start + 2
```

the two log are equal, i think that the line 2 have to contains the method or the line of the crash, in this way is unreadable, i can't understand nothing to solve the problem, i wrong something?

Comment: Please provide more details. E.g. an example crash report after the symbolication process and what you are expecting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash reports are fully symbolicated. There is nothing missing.

You will not get a line number for frame #2, and it would not be helpful anyway. That is PLCrashReporters exception handler that catches all unhandled exceptions, which is the code that makes it happen for you to get this report.

Comment: thanks for the answer, there is a way to understand What caused the crash?

Comment: The crash report should contain a section title `Last Exception Backtrace`.